# Open Picture stored in res/drawable with buildin Android Image Viewer

Tags: android, drawable

is it possible to open an picture, which is stored in the res/drawable folder with the Android build in Image Viewer? I don't get it work. I tried the follwoing way

```
Button ButtonPhase2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ButtonPhase2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("android.resource://de.test.app/" + R.drawable.testbild));
            myIntent.setType("image/png");
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);

        }

    });
```

But I get the Error:

```
Unable to start Activity ComponentInfo{com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ViewImage}: java.lang.nullPointerException
```

I think it is the wrong path?

Answer (score -3):

ya you can do i by this way:
first you need to declare your layout in xml

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/anim_btn_play"
        android:layout_width="155dp" android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp" android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        >
    </ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java file:**

```
ImageButton tns_imgv_back;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.touch_and_show);
        {

        tns_imgv_back= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.anim_btn_play)
        tns_imgv_back.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
             anim_btn_play11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                                       // you can do any thing over here when you click it will fire

                                            }
            });

    }}
```

Comment: May You please define this more precisely, because when I do it this way there won't open something in the buildin Android image viewer, when I click on the icon.